# Rewrite Cond not working

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am trying to write a rewrite condition where

1. It must NOT redirect if I see Server in the URL

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule !^/Server/(.*)$ /redirect.php?page=$1 [L]
> ```

1. But I also want it to go to redirect.php when I dont have Server there. However, the $1 variable is never picking out the content that I am entering. it is always blank

Why?

Answer (score 0):

`(.*)` is never filled, or, better, it's only filled in the case you do not want it, as it is only filled when you have `Server` in the url.

So I think the thing you want is a rewriteCond excluding urls containing `Server` and after that a rewriteRule catching all the content and using it as an argument, this way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Server/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /redirect.php?page=$1 [L]
```